# Compiling Flex Modules - Speed up link-checking?

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc

I'm working on a Flex project that has 28 modules, and 1 main SWF.  Compiling everything takes 18 minutes total.  I'm using load-externs to load a link-report from my main SWF - that works great.  The file size of the modules is minimal.  But link-checking still occurs for each individual module, increasing the compile time dramatically.

So say I edit a file in my main SWF that a module uses.  mxmlc basically performs link-checking for the same file in that module. Even when -incremental=true.  When I edit a file that ALL of the modules reference (which happens frequently), ALL of the modules perform link-checking.  This has the effect of basically compiling the main SWF 28 times.

This is frustrating, because link checking occurs when I compile my first SWF.  It should not have to reoccur for every module.  I tried using fcsh, which would hopefully store these links in memory, but that had no effect.

Maybe it would help to compile a SWC of my main SWF, and use that for link-checking instead?

Here are the commands I use to build:

mxmlc -link-report=report.xml -strict=true -debug=false -optimize=true -incremental=true Project.mxml

mxmlc -load-externs=report.xml -strict=true -debug=false -optimize=true -incremental=true ModuleXX.mxml # 28 times

I haven't found a solution for this problem and it's hindering the development of my project.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Jimmie

Comment: Is it safe to mix -load-externs and -incremental? In my testing, a  change in the Application code proper that causes a relevant change in the link report isn't enough to get the module to rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that 18 minutes is a very long build time, but this kind of module size optimization should only be necessary on a release build. So my simple recommendations are

- Don't use compiler optimization during development time
- Only recompile the modules you are working on
- Upgrade your hardware
- Upgrade your software (the Flex 4 compiler should be faster than Flex 3)

Comment: Thanks splash,

-optimize=false is having very little effect on the build time

Recompiling changed modules is easier said than done.  We push these SWFs into production by the hour, managing the changes in 28 files would be impossible :( That was the goal of using incremental=true, but that has failed.

Is it possible to use the Flex 4 compiler without making many code changes?  I tried it once, even set the target framework to Flex 3.5 like it is currently - seemed like a nightmare.

Comment: I just upgraded to Flash Builder 4 and I got it to run my Flex 3 application without any changes after I configured it to use the Flex 3.5 SDK and the "MX Only" component set.